# How to override Subscription Block at Drupal 8 Simplenews?

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am developing a Drupal 8 website and I want to override the Subscription Block at Simplenews module. I know how to achieve that at Drupal 7, it's from simplenews-block.tpl.php , but the module is different now.
In Drupal-7 I used this to override the block instead of the .module file: http://api.worldempire.ch/api/simplenews/theme%21simplenews-block.tpl.php/7-2. ..I want the equivalent for Drupal-8.

Comment: Please show us your code. So that we can help you more.

Comment: In Drupal-7 I used this to override the block instead of the .mofule file: http://api.worldempire.ch/api/simplenews/theme%21simplenews-block.tpl.php/7-2  ..I want the equivalent for Drupal-8, there is no code involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exact equivalent currently. To override the actual block template for that block you can use 'block--simplenewssubscription.html.twig'. You can use the input and form templates to override other elements. I would suggest enabling debugging in Twig so you can see the template overrides.

Comment: Thanks a lot!After so many days someone actually answered, and it was exactly what I needed!